# Add tags to an existing S3 object using the ruby AWS SDK

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

AWS does let you add tags to an existing S3 bucket, using the console, or this http api for instance: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObjectTagging.html

But rather than use the HTTP API directly, is there any way to use the [ruby AWS SDK v3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/0) to add (or remove?) tags to an existing S3 object?

I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: I'm not sure, I think that's maybe about adding tags to a bucket, not to an object?

Comment: You're right I'm sorry this is the request for the functionality you referenced https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Types/PutObjectTaggingRequest.html

Comment: That class is clearly related functionality, but I don't know how to use it, it looks like a class for a response or something. Have you used this code to accomplish tagging?  Please, answers that you have actually tested and made work would be preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, answering my question, I eventually found a method on Aws::S3::Client

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#put_object_tagging-instance_method

```rb
s3_client = Aws::S3::Client.new
s3_client.put_object_tagging({
                bucket: "bucket_name",
                key: "some/key.jpg",
                tagging: {
                  tag_set: [
                    {
                      key: "tag-name",
                      value: "tag value",
                    }
                  ]
                }
})
```

i was expecting there to be a method on `Aws::S3::Bucket` or `Aws::S3::Object`, but if there is I can't figure it out! But I have verified this one on `Aws::S3::Client` as working for me.